# how to select an option from the popup dropdown list using selenium webdriver c#

Tags: c#, selenium, drop-down-menu, popup

I have a telerik searchbox where I enter 'acc' and it automatically pops up the items starting with 'acc' and from that list I want to select 'Acabose'.

C# code:

```
driver.FindElement(By.Id("ctl00_ctl14_tsfSearch_Input")).Click();
driver.FindElement(By.Id("ctl00_ctl14_tsfSearch_Input")).SendKeys("acc");
```

and HTML:

```
<div class="rsbSlide">
    <div class="rsbPopup">
        <ul class="rsbList">
            <li class="rsbListItem">Acabose</li>
            <li class="rsbListItem">Acabose 100mg</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please read [ask]. Please provide the code you have tried and the execution result including any error messages, etc.

Comment: are you facing any error ? mention that as well

Answer (score 0):

You could get all of the visible li items and iterate through them until you find the option with the text you want. (Note: I work with Selenium in Java, but the principle is the same in c#)

```
// code to enter the search goes here.
List<WebElement> rsbListItems = driver.findElements(By.className("rsbListItem");
for (int i = 0; i < rsbListItems.size(); i++) {
    if (listItem.getText() == "Acabose 100mg") {
        listItem.click();
    }
}
```

Alternatively, if you know that Acabose is always (and forever) going to be the second item in the list, you can access it by index.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below snippet

```
List<WebElement> telerikItemList = driver.findElements(By.className("rsbListItem");
 for (WebElement telerikItemOpt: telerikItemList) {
   if (telerikItemOpt.getText().equals("Acabose 100mg") {
     telerikItemOpt.click();
     break;
   }
 }
```